# How do I associate button events with a unique control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/XDsSt/ with four identical inputs and buttons.The problem is,each section is updates its own unique data in the database so when updating,its important the submit button i click updates the database with the input from that section only.

My function is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".xx").live('click', function(){
         alert('clicked');
         });
        });
```

How do i make sure the button click is unique to that section?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the corresponding section that button belongs to . Then access the elements inside that. You may use the jQuery `closest()`/`parent()`(if only one layer of hierarchy of controls) function for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".xx").live('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  //if you want to prevent normal form submit
       var item=$(this);
       var sectionClicked=item.closest("section");
       //Let's alert the first text box   
       alert(sectionClicked.find("input").first().val());
       //do whatever with the items belongs the current section

     });
});
```

Sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/XDsSt/8/

I recommend you to switch to jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Use an ID value instead for each input button. This way, jQuery can identify it like so:

```
$('#button_tag');
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <input type="text" value="Town">
            <input type="text" value="Mayor">
            <input type="text" value="Highway">
            <input id="btn1" type="submit" class="xx" value="Submit">
        </section>
        <section>
            <input type="text" value="Town">
            <input type="text" value="Mayor">
            <input type="text" value="Highway">
            <input id="btn2" type="submit" class="xx" value="Submit">
        </section>
        <section>
            <input type="text" value="Town">
            <input type="text" value="Mayor">
            <input type="text" value="Highway">
            <input id="btn3" type="submit" class="xx" value="Submit">
        </section>
        <section>
            <input type="text" value="Town">
            <input type="text" value="Mayor">
            <input type="text" value="Highway">
            <input id="btn4" type="submit" class="xx" value="Submit">
        </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".xx").live('click', function () {
        alert('clicked ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

**JsFiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/XDsSt/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".xx").live('click', function() {
        $('section').has(this).find(':input:text').each(function() {
            alert( this.value )            ;
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XDsSt/10/)**

If possible then instead of `.live()`, use `.on()` with jQUery 1.7+, because `live()` is deprecated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.xx', function() {
        $('section').has(this).find(':input:text').each(function() {
            alert( this.value )            ;
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XDsSt/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

if id is not an option - I don't understand that , but you can put multiple classes in buttons

```
           <input type="button" class="xx btn1" ... >

           $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".xx").live('click', function(){   // look into on instead on live
                 if $(this).hasclass('btn1');{
                 alert('clicked');
                      }
                   });
               });
```